Did I already receive a Blue Card from Germany?
I am a non-EU citizen who is in the US and will be moving to Germany for a job. The job meets the EU Blue Card requirements. As per the information available online, I thought I would have to first apply for a National D visa and once I am in Germany, I will have to then apply for the Blue Card residence permit. However, during my visa appointment, I was asked if I wanted a Blue Card, and I said yes.
When I got the passport back, I noticed that my visa was a Type D with remarks that say:
BLAU KARTE EU § 18G (1) S.1 AUFENTHG AUFENTHALTSDAUER ENTSPRICHT GÜLTIGKEIT
I did not pay much attention to it, until now, when I realised that Ausländerbehördes in Berlin only let you apply for the Blue Card residence permit 8 weeks before your 12-month National D visa expires.
My questions are:

Do I already have the Blue Card? I noticed a similar question in another thread but their remarks also included "EWT ERLAUBT" and mine does not. I don't know if this means anything though.

Will I be getting all the benefits of the Blue Card? That is, the opportunity to apply for Permanent Residence in 27 months from the day my visa starts or is it from the day I get the physical card from the Ausländerbehörde? Will my partner also be able to get a family reunification visa based on my visa without having to show German proficiency?


tl;dr: Is my visa a de facto Blue Card until I can apply for the physical card in 10 months?

Should be BLAUE KARTE (with an E at the end of both words), no?

@Relaxed -- I freaked out and then realised I made a copy-paste mistake. But yes, it has an E at the end. :)


Do I already have the Blue Card? I noticed a similar question in another thread but their remarks also included "EWT ERLAUBT" and mine does not. I don't know if this means anything though.

More-or-less. German law makes a distinction between a “title” and a “permit”. Both long-stay visas and residence permits are “titles” and the visa you got entitles you to get the actual permit after entering Germany. So while usually “blue card” is used as a name for the permit itself, the decision has already been made and you are legally entitled to it.
EU law does not make this distinction and some countries handle things differently but what matters most is that you have been approved to work under the Blue Card regime.

Will I be getting all the benefits of the Blue Card? That is, the opportunity to apply for Permanent Residence in 27 months from the day my visa starts or is it from the day I get the physical card from the Ausländerbehörde?

It is neither but rather from the day you start working. The way the law is phrased (Aufenthaltsgesetz § 18c), the requirement is two-pronged:

Being a Blue card holder
Having worked in a “high qualification” occupation and paid retirement contributions for 27 months

You need to have lived and worked in Germany, holding the title or status is not enough, any interruption in your career would also postpone your permanent residence.

Will my partner also be able to get a family reunification visa based on my visa without having to show German proficiency?

In principle yes, as you will get a Blue Card. I am not sure about the exact procedure, though.

Is my visa a de facto Blue Card until I can apply for the physical card in 10 months?

Unless the rules changed recently, I think you can apply sooner than that. It will also take some time before you get the card. But basically yes, it's supposed to be the same.

Thank you for the detailed response. I was more worried about my partner not being able to get a family reunification without the German proficiency test. The rules seem to have changed: https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/en/entry/visa-extension/artikel.1048669.en.php for ones with 1-year D visas. :/

@GanGor That possibility (partner joining you under easier rule) is anchored in the Blue Card directive. Germany can handle the visa and permits any way they want but they may not add arbitrary requirements or unnecessary delays. I assume they are not trying to add illegal restrictions and will handle Blue card D-visa accordingly (but I have no direct experience of that).
